# How does vim detect and handle mouse scroll when started in XTerm?

Tags: unix, vim

Is there an app that can handle mouse scroll in xterm, other than *vim*? I wanted to scroll man pages and *less* won't handle mouse scroll but why is it that *vim* can? Is this because of **curses**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Curses does infact have [mouse support](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/mouse.html). If I remember right wheel-up is button 4 and wheel-down is button 2. It may be system / terminal dependent, I'm not sure.

As for what other apps make use of this feature, [midnight commander](http://www.midnight-commander.org/) and [ranger](http://ranger.nongnu.org/) come to mind.